# How to format an HTML table using CSS for printing?

Tags: html, css

I want to format table using CSS to show an attendance sheet. How do I add CSS styles to the table so that it can be printed?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within your style sheet, use

```
@media print {
  /* put your CSS rules if they are to apply in print only */
}
```

For example,

```
@media print {
   * { color: black; background: white; }
   table { font-size: 80%; }
}
```

The details depend on the types of problems you expect to have with printing your specific table. Generally, if you have set fixed column widths (e.g. in pixels), you probably need to reconsider this part of your design. If you are using colors to convey essential information (e.g., red cell standing for absence, green for presence), you need to reconsider this decision.

Answer (score 4):

use following css

```
table, th, td
{
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width:100%;
  text-align:right;
}
```

also you can use media="print" for print specific layout

Answer (score 2):

Use `media="print"` attribute for your CSS stylesheet to have print specific layout.

Answer (score 2):

you can add media specific css styles to a page using the @media Rule

for example , `@media screen` will use the styles for computer screens and `@media print` is used for printers.

using `@media all` will make sure your styles are applied to all media type devices

follow [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp) for more on media types

Answer (score 1):

Correct all good answers.

What I would do is to make a specific css file just for print and attach it to the page:

```
<link href='/css/theme-print.css' rel='stylesheet' media="print" type='text/css' />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
body {
-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
}
```